# Question about an inference involving an uncountable union of null events

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $P$ and $Q$ be random probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ a probability space. That is, $P: \mathcal{F} \times \Omega\to [0,1]$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ for each fixed $\omega \in \Omega$ and measurable for each fixed $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Same for $Q$.

Let $d$ be the total variation distance, i.e. $d(\mu_1, \mu_2) = \sup_{A \in \mathcal{F}}|\mu_1(A) - \mu_2(A)|$ for any probability measures $\mu_1, \mu_2$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$.

In [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S1755020315000180), I believe that something like the following inference is made (the relevant part is on page 644 in the proof of Theorem 9.2; I'm abstracting away from details in the paper that I believe to be irrelevant to my question). Suppose that for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and for $\mu$ almost every $\omega$ we have
$$|P(A)(\omega) - Q(A)(\omega)| \leq g(\omega),$$
where $g$ is a random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$. Then, taking a supremum over $A \in \mathcal{F}$ yields
$$d(P(\omega), Q(\omega)) \leq g(\omega)$$
for $\mu$ almost every $\omega$.

But this seems problematic to me since there are potentially uncountably many $A$. That is, we know that for each $A \in \mathcal{F}$, there is a $\mu$-null set $F_A$ of points at which the first inequality fails. The set of points at which the second inequality fails is $\cup_A F_A$, which may have positive $\mu$ probability because the union is uncountable.

> Am I correct to be doubtful about this or is the inference valid?

---

**Added.** Actually, the inference in the paper is slightly different from the way I represented it above. But my worry remains and I'd appreciate feedback on both inferences.

Suppose now that for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and for $\mu$ almost every $\omega$ we have
$$|P(A)(\omega) - Q(A)(\omega)| \leq f(A,\omega),$$
where $f$ is a real-valued function on $\mathcal{F} \times \Omega$ satisfying any requisite measurability properties. Then, taking a supremum over $A \in \mathcal{F}$ yields
$$d(P(\omega), Q(\omega)) \leq \sup_{A \in \mathcal{F}}f(A,\omega)$$
for $\mu$ almost every $\omega$.

Now the worry is this. Let $F$ be the set of points at which the last inequality fails and let $\omega_0 \in F$. Then for some $A_0 \in \mathcal{F}$ we have
$$|P(A_0)(\omega_0) - Q(A_0)(\omega_0)| > \sup_A f(A, \omega_0) \geq f(A_0, \omega_0).$$
So $\omega_0$ is a point at which $|P(A)(\omega) - Q(A)(\omega)| \leq f(A,\omega)$ fails for some $A$. Hence, repurposing the notation introduced above, we have $F \subseteq \cup_A F_A$. And $F$ need not have probability $0$ as the union is uncountable, contradicting our inference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the paper you linked, the random measures are in fact functions of a conditional probability. The author is assuming that we have a [regular conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability), and so the statement "for all $A\in\mathcal F$ and for $\mu$ almost every $\omega$ we have $|P(A)(\omega)-Q(A)(\omega)|\le f(A,\omega)$"  should really read "for $\mu$ almost every $\omega$, for every $A\in\mathcal F$ we have...". That is, there exists a null set $F\in\mathcal F$ such that for all $\omega\in\Omega\setminus F$ *and for every* $A\in\mathcal F$ the inequality holds. This gets around your issue.

Incidentally, such issues are why regular conditional probabilities were required in the first place! Indeed, were you asking this question without the context of the paper I believe the answer would be that the conclusion does not follow. (I am sure there are pathological counterexamples to make this precise but I do not know them.)